# Specify a scope in the Previous function

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to create a rule where something is displayed in a certain column only if it is different from the last row in a set.  They are all rows of an order, but i want the rule to restart for every new item in the order.

I am currently using:

```
=IIF(Fields!REL_NO.Value = Previous(Fields!REL_NO.Value), Nothing, Fields!REL_NO.Value)
```

REL_NO being the field I want to hide if the same as last row.  Attached is a picture of my data set showing that rel_no varies.

So the problem I have is that I want it to show on the first row of every item, but the previous clause is only looking at the previous row across all items.  I tried adding the scope (I have a "LINE_NO" group), but that didn't work.  All REL_NOs showed.

### **Showing All Data**

[image]

### **Trying to hide**

[image]

Let me know if you need any more context.

Comment: How should your tablix look like?

Comment: bear with me, but the 7s should go: 7-1 and then just 7. 8s and 9s the same way (all the del nos there are 1).  So only the top del no should show for 7/8/9.  10 should be showing the del no for each line, since they are all different.

Comment: You must have another column to properly order the result. If all 7s are the same, how will the system know which row comes first.

Comment: already have another column that does that to the right, just didn't include it in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this a lightly different way.

Say I have data similar to yours:

[image]

And a simple report based on this data:

[image]

Note that there is a group based on `LINE_NO`, although no header row for the group.

I would achieve your desired result by using the **HideDuplicates** property of the `REL_NO` textbox:

[image]

You can set this with a specific Scope; I have used **DataSet1** here, i.e. consider all rows in the DataSet and not just in the Scope of the `LINE_NO` group.

This seems to be working as intended:

[image]

Comment: My man! Thank you.  Honestly wasn't all too familiar with the properties panel and what it could do.  This worked like a charm.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have another column to sort the rows with the same "Line No", the following quick and dirty query will generate a pseudo one and return the desired result.

```
WITH a (rn, ln, delno)
AS
    (
    select row_number() over( order by "Line No") rn, "Line No" ln, "Del No" delno
    from test
    )

select 
  rn, 
  ln,
  case when delno = (select top 1 delno from a b where b.ln <= a.ln and b.rn < a.rn )
  then cast( null as integer)
  else delno
  end
from a
```